# javascript flot threshold with positive and negative limits (+/-)

Tags: jquery, flot

I need to highlight in red any values that are more than 100% higher or 100% lower than the nominal value, i.e 0 +/- 100.

```
$.plot($("#right"),[{
    data:tot.fdat,
    color:'red',
    threshold:{below:100,color:'green'},
  }]
 })
```

The above works to highlight values higher than +100, but how do I also make it highlight values less than -100 ?

## edit

As suggested by @Kasyx - this works with a slight mod:

```
$.plot($("#right"),[{
    data:tot.fdat,
    color:'red',
    threshold:[
      {below:100,color:'green'},
      {below:-100,color:'red'},
    ]
  }]
 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On github page you can find [jquery.flot.threshold.js](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/jquery.flot.threshold.js):

```
An array can be passed for multiple thresholding, like this:

threshold: [{
    below: number1
    color: color1
},{
    below: number2
    color: color2
}]
```

So in your case it should be something like that:

```
$.plot($("#right"),[{
    data:tot.fdat,
    color:'red',
    threshold:[
        {below:-100,color:'red'},
        {above:100,color:'red'},
    ],
  }]
 })
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that yes that works, but I only appear to be able to use below ranges. I have updated my original post with the edit.

Comment: The above option doesn't work.and it is not released in the latest source code.